# How to change my JS table to html form?

Tags: javascript, html

I rewrite my form into html format already. Thanks for all the help. Actually it is easier to write a form in html than in javascript.

```
<form method = "get" name ="menu">
<img src="item1.jpeg" alt="Doublecook Meat" height="100" width="100">
<br>
<label for="menu1">Doublecook Meat:$15</label>
<input type="text" id="menu1" name="menu1" />

<img src="item2.jpeg" alt="Eggplant Noodle" height="100" width="100">
<br>
<label for="menu2">Eggplant Noodle:$13</label>
<input type="text" id="menu2" name="menu2" />

<img src="item3.jpeg" alt="Fried Rice" height="100" width="100">

<label for="menu3">Fried Rice:$8</label>
<input type="text" id="menu3" name="menu3" />

<img src="item4.jpeg" alt="Ma Po Tofu" height="100" width="100">

<label for="menu4">Ma Po Tofu:$10</label>
<input type="text" id="menu4" name="menu4" />

<img src="item5.jpg" alt="Wonton" height="100" width="100">

<label for="menu5">Wonton:$12</label>
<input type="text" id="menu5" name="menu5" />
<input type="button" id="submit_button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Simply replace the unnecessary table tags with a form tag... Not sure how you would want to use the images in the form though unless you have those as a string value.

Comment: Instead of using `<table>` you use `<form>` and similarly modifying other tags. For example instead of `<td>` you can can use some `<input>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<script>
var price=[15,13,8,10,12]; 
var images=["item1.jpeg","item2.jpeg","item3.jpeg","item4.jpeg","item5.jpg"]; 
var titles=["Doublecook Meat","Eggplant Noodle","Fried Rice","Ma Po Tofu","Wonton"]; 
document.write("<form name=\"form\" action=\"action.php\">");
for(i=0;i<5;i++) 
{
document.write("<img src= "+images[i]+" width=100 height=100><label>Item Name</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"input[][title]\" value=\""+titles[i]+"\"><label>Price</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"input[][price]\"value=\""+price[i]+"\"><br />"); 
}
document.write("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Send\">"); 
document.write("</form>"); 
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think it will work.The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.

Comment: thanks for your help, but the form does not show with your code.

Comment: It does work https://jsfiddle.net/tfvhmszL/ but I don't recommend using `document.write()`. You could use `document.createElement()` and append the new elements created or you can build a string of those elements in a variable and then append or set via `.innerHTML`

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I finally rewrite this form in html, actually that's easier to write a form in html than in javascript.